Nav displaying only on scroll up treshold
I want to make the nav slide out only when scrolling up and in the current configuration it works, only there is one problem because at the minimum scroll down navVisible is set to false and disappears and after a while it appears again. How can i make treshold so that minimal scroll down doesn't make a change?
const [prevScrollPos, setPrevScrollPos] = useState(0);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const navHidden = 'top-[-100%] transition ease-out duration-300';
  const navVisible =
    ' w-full fixed top-0 z-50 duration-300 bg-white shadow-card';
  const handleNav = () => {
    setMenuOpen(!menuOpen);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const currentScrollPos = window.scrollY;
      if (window.scrollY <= window.innerHeight) {
        setVisible(false);
      } else {
        setVisible(prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos);
        setPrevScrollPos(currentScrollPos);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [prevScrollPos]);

  return (
    <header
      className={`padding-x py-8 block ${visible ? navVisible : navHidden}`}

